# From expected value of R2 in Regression to expected value of partial eta squared in ANOVA

Tags: r, distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, f-distribution

In general, $R^2$, the estimator of **"multiple correlation coefficient"** in regression, is known to be positively biased. Given $K$ predictors, and $N$ total sample size, [Johnson, Kotz, & Balakrishnan, 1995, Vol. 2, p. 621](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Continuous+Univariate+Distributions%2C+Volume+2%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471584940), provide the correct expected value of $R^2$ as follows (*Equation 1*):

[image]

where $P^2$ is the population value of $R^2$, and $H$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

The distribution of $R^2$ is also known to be a non-central $F$ distribution with $K = df1$, $N - K - 1 = df2$, and the non-centrality parameter ($ncp$) of $(N \times R^2) / (1 - R^2)$.

## Question:

Partial eta-squared $(\eta_p^2)$ in ANOVA is exactly distributed like $R^2$ except that $K -1 = df1$, $N - K = df2$, and the non-centrality parameter ($ncp$) of $(N \times \eta_p^2) / (1 - \eta_p^2)$.

**My question** is, is it possible to re-express the *Equation 1* for partial eta-Squared?

Below, I'm showing an `R` implementation of *Equation 1* for $R^2$ which I hope to be able modify to work for partial eta-Squared (I appreciate a possible `R` implementation).

```
library(gsl) # used for hypergeometric function

expected.R2 <- function(P2, K, N) {
  Value <- 1 - ((N - K - 1)/(N - 1)) * (1 - P2) * 
  gsl::hyperg_2F1(1, 1, 0.5 * (N + 1), P2)
  Value <- max(0, Value)
  return(Value)
}
# Example of use:
expected.R2(P2 = .2, K = 2, N = 120)
```

Comment: The equation remains the same, only the values of df1 and df2 and $P^2$ change. Instead of K you now have K-1 and instead of N-K-1 you now have N-K and lastly instead of P^2 you now have the Population value for the partial-eta squared

Comment: The answer is exactly what you have above. The code that you wrote is the answer. The difference is the input values

Comment: Just rewrite the above function using the degrees of freedom ie where there is k-1 replace with df1 and where there is N-K-1 replace with df2 then you will see what I mean

Comment: imagine i give you have `pf(q,df1=k,df2=n-k-1,cpn=..)` you will change it to `pf(q,df1=k-1,df2=n-k-1,ncp=..)` did the underlying equation change?? it did not. It remained the same. The input values changed. Thats what i mean. You just need to modify the inputs and retain the equation or vice versa

Comment: thus using your R equation above, add 1 to the input of k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a degrees of freedom issue:

we can rerwite:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&1-\frac{N-K-1}{N-1}(1-p^2)H[1;1;\frac{N+1}{2};P^2]\\
&1-\frac{N-df1-1}{N-1}(1-\eta^2)H[1;1;\frac{N+1}{2};\eta^2]\quad\text{Changed } K \text{ to } df1\\
&1-\frac{N-(K-1)-1}{N-1}(1-\eta^2)H[1;1;\frac{N+1}{2};\eta^2]\\
&1-\frac{N-K}{N-1}(1-\eta^2)H[1;1;\frac{N+1}{2};\eta^2]
\end{aligned}$$

```
library(gsl) # used for hypergeometric function

expected.R2 <- function(P2, K, N) {
  Value <- 1 - ((N - K - 1)/(N - 1)) * (1 - P2) * 
  gsl::hyperg_2F1(1, 1, 0.5 * (N + 1), P2)
  Value <- max(0, Value)
  return(Value)
}
# Example of use:
expected.R2(P2 = .2, K = 2+1, N = 120)
```

or:

```
library(gsl) # used for hypergeometric function

expected.R2 <- function(P2, K, N) {
  Value <- 1 - ((N - K)/(N - 1)) * (1 - P2) * 
  gsl::hyperg_2F1(1, 1, 0.5 * (N + 1), P2)
  Value <- max(0, Value)
  return(Value)
}
# Example of use:
expected.R2(P2 = .2, K = 2, N = 120)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As $\eta_p^2$ and $R^2$ each come with their own unique $df1$, no change to my *Equation 1* was needed.